# Is a word 'firm' used with 'with'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When I am sure about something and want to say

> I can be firm with that.

Is this usage grammatically correct with using 'with'?

Comment: It would be much better if you wrote a short dialogue, or a longer example where you would use this term. Then users could say whether "firm" is used appropriately or not.

Comment: There's simply not enough context for us to make a judgment, but my initial reaction is that "firm with" is unusual. The collocation "firm on" is what comes immediately to mind.

Comment: Idiomatically, it sounds like "My position on that is firm."  Or, "If you think it will help us negotiate a better deal, I can be firm on that."  If you're just learning the language, it's good to develop a prejudice in favor of verbs over nouns and adjectives.  Wherever "I insist on" can replace "I am firm on/about," the choice with the active verb is almost always better.

Answer (score -1):

I entered "firm.[jj*] with" into the iWeb Corpus and it returned 1367 results. So "firm with" is absolutely grammatically correct. Ex: You just have to be firm with some people to get to the point and get shit Done. I had to be firm with them and tell them to CUT IT OUT. I was afraid to be firm with my students. BUT "be firm with" is followed by people while "be firm on" is followed by something. Ex: " We are very firm on this, " he insisted.  The president has been very, very firm on that. I don't feel like he is really firm on any real issues.

Comment: It depends on what one wants to say.  "firm with *that*" is not the same as "firm with some people" or "firm with them".